# How do I keep screen ON when I close laptop lid on my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS server?

Tags: server, laptop, screen

I have already changed
`/etc/systemd/logind.conf`
So that the server doesn't suspend when I close the lid but I want the screen to stay on, currently it turns black.

Comment: Are you wanting an external monitor to stay on when you close the lid?

Comment: @TheXed I have install xubuntu on the server and want to use the X2Go client. Some graphical applications doesn't work when the screen is off.

Comment: Oh I see...interesting use case...however it seems like that the link that @User24601 should point you in the correct direction.